# AngularJS Sorting for multiple ng-repeats

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I am working on creating a schedule for which we have created a JSON like following

```
{
  "cancelledWeeks": {
    "1511548200": [
      {
        "match_id": "e06d20944182aa2b5ead43e8990e5985",
        "reason": "chhj",
        "round": 1,
        "team1": "team_id_17101711595974",
        "date": 1511548200,
        "team1_color_code": "#1f1818",
        "team1_name": "17October team",
        "team2": "team_id_1710179490074",            
        "team2_color_code": "#302929",
        "team2_name": "cms team 4",
        "time": "6:30 PM"
      },
      {
        "match_id": "4715cf8897663e5474feaa14ef396674",
        "reason": "chhj",
        "round": 1,
        "team1": "team_id_17101712185745",
        "date": 1511548200,
        "team1_color_code": "#1f0606",
        "team1_name": "october 19",
        "team2": "team_id_1710179420033",
        "team2_color_code": "#363cba",
        "team2_name": "cms team 3",
        "time": "7:05 PM"
      }
    ],
    "1513967400": [
      {
        "match_id": "1e916238a526644194daa263906c7a23",
        "reason": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,",
        "round": 5,
        "team1": "team_id_1710179420033",
        "date": 1513967400,
        "team1_color_code": "#363cba",
        "team1_name": "cms team 3",
        "team2": "team_id_17101711595974",            
        "team2_color_code": "#1f1818",
        "team2_name": "17October team",
        "time": "6:30 PM"
      },
      {
        "date": 1513967400,
        "match_id": "91ec5c9469c55cdb7426a92c19a2309a",
        "reason": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,",
        "round": 5,
        "team1": "team_id_17101711441450",            
        "team1_color_code": "#36ba63",
        "team1_name": "web team 2",
        "team2": "team_id_17101717102231",           
        "team2_color_code": "#faf352",
        "team2_name": "Retest team 17",
        "time": "7:05 PM"
      }
    ]
  },
  "rainoutWeeks": {
    "1514572200": [
      {
        "match_id": "e06d20944182aa2b5ead43e8990e5985",
        "round": 1,
        "team1": "team_id_17101711595974",
        "date": 1514572200,
        "team1_color_code": "#1f1818",
        "team1_name": "17October team",
        "team2": "team_id_1710179490074",            
        "team2_color_code": "#302929",
        "team2_name": "cms team 4",
        "time": "6:30 PM"
      },
      {
        "match_id": "4715cf8897663e5474feaa14ef396674",
        "round": 1,
        "team1": "team_id_17101712185745",
        "date": 1514572200,**strong text**
        "team1_color_code": "#1f0606",
        "team1_name": "october 19",
        "team2": "team_id_1710179420033",            
        "team2_color_code": "#363cba",
        "team2_name": "cms team 3",
        "time": "7:05 PM"
      }
    ]
  },
  "schedule": {
    "1514448462": [
      {
        "match_id": "e06d20944182aa2b5ead43e8990e5985",
        "round": 1,
        "team1": "team_id_17101711595974",
        "date": 1514448462,
        "team1_color_code": "#1f1818",
        "team1_name": "17October team",
        "team2": "team_id_1710179490074",
        "team2_color_code": "#302929",
        "team2_name": "cms team 4",
        "time": "6:30 PM"
      },
      {
        "match_id": "4715cf8897663e5474feaa14ef396674",
        "round": 1,
        "team1": "team_id_17101712185745",
        "date": 1514448462,
        "team1_color_code": "#1f0606",
        "team1_name": "october 19",
        "team2": "team_id_1710179420033",
        "team2_color_code": "#363cba",
        "team2_name": "cms team 3",
        "time": "7:05 PM"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am repeating rows with different keys like

```
<tr ng-repeat="schedule_data.schedule")
<tr ng-repeat="schedule_data.rainoutWeeks")
<tr ng-repeat="schedule_data.cancelledWeeks")
```

I want to sort all rows according to dates and I can't merge the array, as I am using some edit operations corresponding to each schedule type, and can't change the process.

Is there any solution which will work for current scenario?

Comment: Can you share your expaction output?

Comment: Are `1511548200` `1513967400` etc are dates?

Comment: Try creating a filter which takes all the data and sort it according to the filter value (date in your case). The filter method can merge all the data and return the sorted result. That would keep the actual data and the filtered result different.

Comment: @VicJordan yes 1511548200 1513967400 are timestamp

Comment: @bipinpatel  I want to sort data according to date irrespective of the keys like schedule, cancelledWeeks and rainoutWeeks. Solution without changing my JSON structure is required

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create custom filter 
Here is full code for your solution

> if you want change order than just pass false like this
>   orderObjectBy:key:false

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,val) in schedule_data | orderObjectBy:key:true">
    {{val}}
    <br>
</li>

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
  return function(items, field, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    var data = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
        angular.forEach(value, function(subvalue, subkey) {
            var obj = {"key":subkey,"value":key}
            filtered.push(obj);
        });
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      return (a['key'] > b['key'] ? 1 : -1);
    });
    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
    var returnData = [];
    angular.forEach(filtered, function(obj, key) {
        returnData.push(items[obj['value']][obj['key']]);
    });
    return returnData;
  };
});

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.schedule_data = {
  "cancelledWeeks": {
    "2": [
      {
        "match_id": "e06d20944182aa2b5ead43e8990e5985",
        "reason": "chhj",
        "round": 1,
        "team1": "team_id_17101711595974",
        "team1_captains": {

        },
        "team1_color_code": "#1f1818",
        "team1_name": "17October team",
        "team2": "team_id_1710179490074",
        "team2_captains": {

        },
        "team2_color_code": "#302929",
        "team2_name": "cms team 4",
        "time": "6:30 PM"
      },
      {
        "match_id": "4715cf8897663e5474feaa14ef396674",
        "reason": "chhj",
        "round": 1,
        "team1": "team_id_17101712185745",
        "team1_captains": {

        },
        "team1_color_code": "#1f0606",
        "team1_name": "october 19",
        "team2": "team_id_1710179420033",
        "team2_captains": {

        },
        "team2_color_code": "#363cba",
        "team2_name": "cms team 3",
        "time": "7:05 PM"
      }
    ],
    "4": [
      {
        "match_id": "1e916238a526644194daa263906c7a23",
        "reason": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,",
        "round": 5,
        "team1": "team_id_1710179420033",
        "team1_captains": {

        },
        "team1_color_code": "#363cba",
        "team1_name": "cms team 3",
        "team2": "team_id_17101711595974",
        "team2_captains": {

        },
        "team2_color_code": "#1f1818",
        "team2_name": "17October team",
        "time": "6:30 PM"
      },
      {
        "date": 1513967400,
        "location": "loc_id_17092712170130",
        "match_id": "91ec5c9469c55cdb7426a92c19a2309a",
        "reason": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,",
        "round": 5,
        "team1": "team_id_17101711441450",
        "team1_captains": {

        },
        "team1_color_code": "#36ba63",
        "team1_name": "web team 2",
        "team2": "team_id_17101717102231",
        "team2_captains": {

        },
        "team2_color_code": "#faf352",
        "team2_name": "Retest team 17",
        "time": "7:05 PM"
      }
    ]
  },
  "rainoutWeeks": {
    "5": [
      {
        "match_id": "e06d20944182aa2b5ead43e8990e5985",
        "round": 1,
        "team1": "team_id_17101711595974",
        "team1_captains": {

        },
        "team1_color_code": "#1f1818",
        "team1_name": "17October team",
        "team2": "team_id_1710179490074",
        "team2_captains": {

        },
        "team2_color_code": "#302929",
        "team2_name": "cms team 4",
        "time": "6:30 PM"
      },
      {
        "match_id": "4715cf8897663e5474feaa14ef396674",
        "round": 1,
        "team1": "team_id_17101712185745",
        "team1_captains": {

        },
        "team1_color_code": "#1f0606",
        "team1_name": "october 19",
        "team2": "team_id_1710179420033",
        "team2_captains": {

        },
        "team2_color_code": "#363cba",
        "team2_name": "cms team 3",
        "time": "7:05 PM"
      }
    ]
  },
  "schedule": {
    "1": [
      {
        "match_id": "e06d20944182aa2b5ead43e8990e5985",
        "round": 1,
        "team1": "team_id_17101711595974",
        "team1_captains": {

        },
        "team1_color_code": "#1f1818",
        "team1_name": "17October team",
        "team2": "team_id_1710179490074",
        "team2_captains": {

        },
        "team2_color_code": "#302929",
        "team2_name": "cms team 4",
        "time": "6:30 PM"
      },
      {
        "match_id": "4715cf8897663e5474feaa14ef396674",
        "round": 1,
        "team1": "team_id_17101712185745",
        "team1_captains": {

        },
        "team1_color_code": "#1f0606",
        "team1_name": "october 19",
        "team2": "team_id_1710179420033",
        "team2_captains": {

        },
        "team2_color_code": "#363cba",
        "team2_name": "cms team 3",
        "time": "7:05 PM"
      }
    ]
  }
};
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my case. I want to show data according to dates irrespective of the keys it exists